# Overriding Functions result in multiple definitions error

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I am attempting to setup an Employee base case and a Hourly/Salaried/Commissioned Employee subclasses. When I try to compile I am getting the following errors:

```
HourlyEmployee.o: In function `getInfo()':
/cygdrive/d/HourlyEmployee.cpp:4: multiple definition of `func1()'
Employee.o:/cygdrive/d/subclass.cpp:4: first defined here
HourlyEmployee.o: In function `getEarning()':
/cygdrive/d/HourlyEmployee.cpp:9: multiple definition of `func2()'
Employee.o:/cygdrive/subclass.cpp:9: first defined here
```

Below is my code, it is very bare as I am simply trying to setup inheritence/overriding of functions.

subclass.cpp

```
#include "subclass.h"

string func1(/* arguments */) {
  /* code */
  return 0;
}

double func2(/* arguments */) {
  /* code */
  return 0;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: you are missing classname:: before the function definitions. aka HourlyEmployee::getInfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining a member function, yuo have to use the `ClassName::` notation, i.e.

```
#include "HourlyEmployee.h"

string HourlyEmployee::getInfo(/* arguments */) {
  /* code */
  return 0;
}

double HourlyEmployee::getEarning(/* arguments */) {
  /* code */
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That worked thank you! Is it possible that in some scenarios that is not needed? Another person with the same project did not use that  ClassName:: notation, yet their files compiled just fine.

Comment: only if you defining within the class declaration, such `class myClass:{ int GetInt() {return 1;}};` if you are outside class declaration and don't use `myClass::` you are just defining a function not related to any class